# floating DockableContent position

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm not sure my terminology is right, but when I undock a (DockableContent) tab, I can leave it floating on my desktop, as if it was a toolwindow.  Top and Left don't seem to be available properties.  How can I determine its position onscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's floating on your desktop, the `DockableContent` is inside a `FloatingWindow` ([Link](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GettingStarted&referringTitle=Documentation)).  "Walk up the tree" (recursive get parent) until you get a non-null `Window` object, then use `Top` and `Left`.